# Getting the position of a dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, socket.io, dynamically-generated

I am making a board game. The board gets added dynamically after a match is made, and the size is determined uniquely for each player based on their screen size. This means to place pieces properly I need to know where the board is in the DOM

```
$(document).on('click', '#boardOverlay', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var offset = $(this).offset();

    alert("offset.left: " + offset.left + " offset.top: " + offset.top );

    var move = {};

    var mouseX = event.pageX - offset.left; 
    var mouseY = event.pageY - offset.top;


    move.Y = Math.floor(mouseX / board.piece_length);
    move.X = Math.floor(mouseY / board.piece_length);

    socket.emit('move', move, board.color);

});
```

Before the alert statement gets executed Chrome is throwing this error at me

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientTop' of null    jquery.min.js:4
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked into both the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and think that offset is the correct choice but have not had luck with either.

**Note:** The `.on()` methode is working because if I leave the board in the top left corner and assume values of 0 for `offset.left` and `offset.top` this function works fine.

**Update:** Here is the JQuery line which is throwing the error

```
clientTop  = docElem.clientTop  || body.clientTop  || 0;
```

which is line 9264 of the non-minified version

Comment: always use full development version of jQuery to debug... can look at line that is being used and get better idea what is calling that line. Minified version is too hard to decifer

Comment: by that do you mean download the developer version and link to that? currently I'm using `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: just remove `.min` from url. google has both versions. Then will get line numbers in the thousands and in console can click and see method being used

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` not a good idea when handler is delegated. By definition of event delegation the event has to propagate to selector, in your case `document`

Comment: The error occurs both with or without `event.stopPropagation();` but I included it because they had it in the example in the jQuery documentation for the `.offset()` function. I will take it out though, Thanks

Comment: have you tried other browser? Seems strange.. the `||` should stop any error thrown and set value to zero

Comment: also try update jQuery version just in case offset was updated...using just `1.8` in google url will get most recent version which is 1.8.3

Comment: I updated jquery and the problem is still persisting. Also I tried it in firefox and it says `> TypeError: body is null` and gives me the same line 9264

Comment: try `console.log(this)` and see what  it shows in console. Also make sure page is valid on W3C validator

Comment: `console.log(this)` outputs `<div id="boardOverlay"></div>`

Comment: no idea what problem is...works fine doing simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/6LaQz/1/  Maybe something in your css causing issue, or insertion code. See if you can replicate problem in jsfiddle.net

Comment: one other thought..I have no idea what `socket.io` is ..maybe it conflicts somehow

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try accessing the attributes directly:

```
$(document).on('click', '#boardOverlay', function(event){
 var top = $(this).css("top");
 var left = $(this).css("left");
});
```

Comment: Its returning undefined for both of these. I dont think div tags have `left` and `right` attributes

Comment: `top` and `left` are not attributes...they are part of `style` properties if defined in css. Also not the same as `offset` which is posiion within document

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right, changed the example to .css instead of .attr

Comment: unfortunately using css also requires chasing all the positioned parents up the tree to figure out offset